# Compare list of dictionary in Robot Framework

Tags: python, list, dictionary, robotframework

I have two Dictionaries of list of dictionary and I want to compare the value of first list dictionary to second list of dictionary

For example:

```
Dictionary A contains [{Name:C}, {Name:A}, {Name:B}]
Dictionary B contains [{Name:A}, {Name:B}, {Name:C}]
```

How to take A's 1st Dictionary {Name:C} and check if it exists in Dictionary B.

Comment: Could you elaborate your question, and paste your code? Do you have 2 "list of dicts" or a "list of list of dicts"?

Answer (score 0):

You want to see if some list of dictionaries contains at least one dictionary that maps `'name': 'C'` ?

```
any(d['name'] == 'C' for d in list_of_dict if 'name' in dict)
```

Comment: I want to compare both the list of Dictionaries value and returns true if both Dictionaries values are same. I am trying in robot framework. Would appreciate if you would help in Robot framework.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to do this using the built in Collections library. This code took the values in one dictionary and checked to see if the value exists in the other.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections

*** Variables ***
&{DICTONARY_ONE} =  name1=a  name2=b  name3=c  name4=d
&{DICTONARY_TWO} =  name1=c  name2=a  name3=d  name4=b

*** Test Cases ***
Dictonary Test
    @{dictonary2_list} =  Get Dictionary Values  ${DICTONARY_TWO}
    :For  ${item}  in  @{dictonary2_list}
    \   Dictionary Should Contain Value  ${DICTONARY_ONE}  ${item}
```

If this is not quite what you are after, there should be something in collections that will let you do what you need. Here is a link to the documentation.
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html

I hope that helps.

Comment: How about if i have list of dictionaries. I have tried the above test case with list of dictionaries but i couldn't see the result

Answer (score 0):

Be it a dictionary or string, as long as it is a part of list it can be compared.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections

*** Test Case ***
Dictionary Validation
    ${dict1}=   Create Dictionary   Name    A
    ${dict2}=   Create Dictionary   Name    B
    ${dict3}=   Create Dictionary   Name    C       
    @{li}=  Create List  ${dict3}  ${dict1}  ${dict2}
    @{lj}=  Create List  ${dict1}  ${dict2}  ${dict3}

    FOR    ${item1}    IN    @{li}
        List Should Contain Value  ${lj}  ${item1}
    END
    FOR    ${item1}    IN    @{lj}
        List Should Contain Value  ${li}  ${item1}
    END
```

Just in-case the comparison is on a part of dictionary (not complete dictionary), we need to think of another way. Let me know if it helps!